# Selenium UnreachableBrowserException - “Could not start a new session” in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, exception, selenium-webdriver, automation, phantomjs

When I try to connect to facebook.com through PhantomJS I receive this error. I could not find a solution.

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

    public class SeleniumDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "E:/ProjectTrials/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");
        System.out.println("c1");
        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
        System.out.println("c2");
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
        System.out.println("c3");
        System.out.println("Page Title:  " + driver.getTitle());
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried with other drivers ? Have you tried to run directly the drivers exe to test execution rights and if the exe version is compatible with your OS ?

Comment: `Selenium-Java Client` version?

Comment: I have no problem with other drivers but this one :/. i will try directly to execute. thx i could not think that :).